# Correctly sizing Alsa buffers, weird API

Tags: c, api, alsa

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to do some sampling with Alsa. I'm trying to configure correctly everything but I'm stuck on how to correctly size my reading.

There are two primitives that seem to be interesting for my task:

```
snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time
snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size
```

The name of the first one suggests that the output will be the time length of a sampling period, however that's weird: if I'm setting the sampling rate on `f = 44100Hz` the sampling period (in nanoseconds) should be `T0 = 1e9 / 44100 ~=  22676 ns` while the function will answer `T1 = 725 us  = 725000 ns`.

Meanwhile, even if I've been asked to use non-locking primitives, I'm trying to profile the time required for locking 'readi', and it turns out that the sample requires `T2 =  8028603 ns` in the best case time and `T3 = 12436217 ns` in the worst case.

Finally I can't figure out what's the meaning of the following two:

```
snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_time
snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size
```

I don't get how could I measure the buffer in time and the period in size, However the former returns the same value as `get_buffer_size`, while the latter returns the same value as `get_period_time`.

Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my soundcard initialization function.

First of all I set needed parameters

```
static
int init_soundcard (snd_pcm_t *handle, unsigned *rate, uint8_t channels,
                    snd_pcm_uframes_t *nframes, unsigned *period)
{
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hwparams;
    int err;

    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&hwparams);

    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, hwparams);
    if (err < 0) return err;

    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, hwparams, rate, NULL);
    if (err < 0) return err;

    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, hwparams,
                                       SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);
    if (err < 0) return err;

    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, hwparams,
                                       SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);
    if (err < 0) return err;

    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, hwparams, channels);
    if (err < 0) return err;
```

When every parameter has been setted correctly, the parameters are applied to the handle:

```
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, hwparams);
    if (err < 0) return err;
```

*After* it has been applied the brave programmer can obtain the required data as follows:

get_period_size_min() gives the minimum size in frames of the buffer that will contain the sampling. A buffer having this size is wide enough.

```
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size_min(hwparams, nframes, NULL);
    if (err < 0) return err;
```

This is pretty counter-intuitive, but the correct sampling period is not given by 1/rate as one may think. One can obtain the sampling period by using the get_period_time() primitive!

```
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(hwparams, period, NULL);
    if (err < 0) return err;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

ALSA has some weird^Wspecific terminology:

- Frames: samples x channels (i.e: stereo frames are composed of two samples, mono frames are composed of 1 sample,...)
- Period: Number of samples tranferred after which the device acknowledges the transfer to the apllication (usually via an interrupt).

The *_size functions appear to return sizes in frames.

HTH

Comment: What they return is clear by the return type, which is `snd_uframe_t` for *_size and `unsigned` for *_time, but I don't get what's the meaning of "buffer time" and "period size".

Comment: Period size:
val     Returned approximate period size in frames

Buffer time (of course it depends on current configuration):
val     Returned buffer time in us

Comment: Yes, the documentation has the same informative content of the function name, but what is a buffer time? The buffer has a certain *size*, not a *time*.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood using and reading the ALSA library, this period is related to the hardware interruptions being made. If you use

```
snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size()
```

It will return you the number of frames passed to the hw by interruption. Similarly, if you use

```
snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time()
```

You will get the time in us (10^-6) that those frames will be inserted. So the "real" sampling rate can be obtained if

```
snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size()*1000000/snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time()
```